# Limits on Shopify metafields

Tags: shopify

I was wondering what the limits were on the number of metafields that an entity in Shopify could have. For instance, under a given namespace for a product object, could you have 1000 unique key value pairs? Is there a hard limit?

Please note I have consulted the documentation on Shopify's Metafield API page (http://api.shopify.com/metafield.html) but it only states the following limits:

The namespace has a maximum of 20 characters, and the key has a maximum of 30 characters.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hard limit, but if you're storing that much info you might want to consider doing it locally as retrieving it will become a pain.

Comment: Thank you for weighing in Mr. Underwood. Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The most metafields that we've applied to any given element to date is **5434**. We have a collection that currently contains that many metafields, and it seems to be working fine!

I wouldn't advise doing this, as it's a nightmare to find and remove any via Postman if manual intervention is required. But it's certainly possible!

Answer (score 0):

If you had the following
MyNS.Key1 = 1
MyNS.Key2 = 2
...
MyNS.Key1000 = 1000

You should be able to access it like 
products.metafields.MyNS[someKey]

So not too difficult to retrieve, or am i missing something else