# Size limit for a single shopify meta field

Tags: shopify

Is there any size limitation on a single Shopify Meta Field.?

like, upto 1kb of data only allowed to store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The value is limited to 65,535 characters, the same as a MySQL TEXT column.
Keys are limited to 30 characters and the namespace is limited to 20 characters.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shopify-app-discuss/os_Ll7PChGg/jpQgOKwSANEJ
http://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield#create

Comment: And for reference, the metafield description field is limited to 255 characters. If you attempt to save anything larger you'll get this error: {'description': ['is too long (maximum is 255 characters)']}

Answer (score 3):

[The key is limited to 30 characters, and the namespace has a maximum of 20 characters](http://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield#properties).

Regarding the length of the value, [see here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shopify-app-discuss/os_Ll7PChGg/n28q9xyxVfYJ):

> The current implementation of a metafield value field is a MySQL TEXT
>   column... a TEXT column has a maximum
>   length of 65535 (2^16 - 1) characters. I’m not encouraging you to
>   start storing enormous blobs, but the limit is pretty big.

Also, there is no limit on how many metafields you can have (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715506/limits-on-shopify-metafields) and [here](http://www.shopify.com.au/technology/3032322-new-feature-metafields)).